# Shapely Intersection, registering that there is an intersection but not calculating area properly

Tags: python, geojson, shapely

I am having trouble calculating the area of an intersection of two shapely GeometryCollections which have been created from two GeoJSON multipolygons that represent drivetimes.

I want to check for two possible scenarios and have set up test data.

In the first scenario, one drivetime is wholly within the other drivetime and I have confirmed this is the case through rendering the drivetimes on a folium map in Jupyter. I assume that in this case I can just use ".within" and, if it returns "True", I can apportion 100% of the smaller catchment to the area shared?

But in the second scenario, visually far more than 95% of the smaller catchment is clearly within the larger one when the GeoJSON shapes are rendered on the folium map but when I use the following code, it only registers that 49% is within the area. Is the conversion from GeoJSON multipolygon to Shapely that I am using, losing the relative scale of the actual catchments?

My code and outputs, along with photos of the catchments are below, if someone could tell me where I am going wrong in calculating the size of the intersection, that would be great.

```
from shapely.geometry import GeometryCollection, shape

catchment1 = GeometryCollection([shape(value[0][1]['data']['features'][0]['geometry']).buffer(0) for feature in features])
catchment2 = GeometryCollection([shape(value[1][1]['data']['features'][0]['geometry']).buffer(0) for feature in features])

if catchment2.within(catchment1):
    print("Within")
else:
    print("Not Within")
    if catchment1.intersects(catchment2):
        print("intersects")
        print(f"Shape 1 Area: {catchment1.area}")
        print(f"Shape 2 Area: {catchment2.area}")
        print(f"Shape 2 Area as a percentage of Shape1 Area {(catchment2.area/catchment1.area) * 100}")


        print(f"Intersection {catchment1.intersects(catchment2)}")
        print(f"Intersection Area1 : {catchment1.intersection(catchment2).area}")
        print(f"Intersection Area1 : {catchment2.intersection(catchment1).area}")

        print(f"Percentage of area 2 in intersection {(catchment1.intersection(catchment2).area/catchment2.area)*100}")
    else:
        print("does not intersect")
```

And the output I am getting is:

```
Not Within
intersects
Shape 1 Area: 0.026273957817
Shape 2 Area: 0.015491099132000195
Shape 2 Area as a percentage of Shape1 Area 58.959899532064455
Intersection True
Intersection Area1 : 0.0076861602514691355
Intersection Area1 : 0.0076861602514691225
Percentage of area 2 in intersection 49.616622977976554
```

Catchment 1
[image]

Catchment 2
[image]

Answer (score 0):

When I remove ".buffer(0) for feature in features]" from the shape command, the relative size of the areas matches the map accurately.